# Reading data from multiple $.get() using $.when()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery's `$.when()` to handle multiple `$.get()` requests. This is how I have it set up.

```
var request1 = $.get('myURL');
var request2 = $.get('mySecondURL');

$.when(request1, request2).done(go);

function go(request1, request2){
    console.log(request1);
    console.log(request2);
}
```

Everything works great. Chrome's console shows

```
[#document, "success", Object]
```

I know that `#document` is what I need to read, but what is the syntax to get it? Every example I've seen uses anonymous functions, which I'm not use to and bug me, coming from **OOP AS3**.

I've tried `console.log(request1[0]);` which works, but there has to be a more proper way. Something like `request1.data` or `$(request1).$('#document');`

Like I said, I'm a heavy Flex developer coming into JS and jQuery so the syntax I'm still trying to pickup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), `request1[2]` has the `jqXHR` object, which in turn has `responseText` member.  If you use `console.log` in Chrome at least, you can see the contents of the `jqXHR` to find what member you specifically want to access, but it's probably `responseText`.

Comment: I guess it's safe to assume that `request1[2]` will always be the jqXHR object then? This will work coding it that way. Without using a `console.log` how would you find out what the array is holding and which index is the data needed?

Comment: @IamFace I did some more research and it turns out that if you have only one argument to `when`, it extracts the array (terrible behavior IMO) so the first argument will actually be the response text.  `request1[0]` is also the response text, as a string.  You can go ahead and use that instead of searching through `jqXHR`.  You can treat it as a string, or use `$(request1[0])` (or possibly just `$(request1)` DOM-ify it.

Comment: The response text will just be XML coming back, that I'll need to parse, but in this case yeah I'll just use `request1[0]` to pull it. I was hoping it would be a little easier to get with a static property like `request1.data` rather than array 'request1[0]`, but if it works, it works :P
Thanks for the help

Comment: @IamFace that's just a property of `.when`.  You could always handle it some different way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a jQuery object and use it like you would use one created from a selector: `$(request1)`

For example, `$(request1).appendTo('#out')` would append the newly loaded content to an element with `id="out"`.